# How to import custom field of plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have install plugin **Yoast SEO Premium**,
with this plugin have some field is

```
yoast_wpseo_metadesc,yoast_wpseo_focuskw
```

but I can't add althought I used:

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'yoast_wpseo_metadesc',$my_post['post_excerpt']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem may be due to several concerns, here are some ideas :

## Prefix meta keys with "_"

Yoast SEO prefix these custom fields entries with a "_" in the database. The key is not "yoast_wpseo_metadesc" but "_yoast_wpseo_metadesc". Same for "yoast_wpseo_focuskw", it's actually "_yoast_wpseo_focuskw".

## Use update_post_meta() instead of add_post_meta()

Add_post_meta() can create a custom field for a post if the field does not exist. If it exists, it does not update it. It's always better to use the update_post_meta() function, more flexible. If the custom field already exists, it will be updated. Otherwise, the function will call add_post_meta() to create it.
In your case, a field maybe already exists with that name.

## Be careful to where you execute your code

I think we need more information on where you launch your add_post_meta() function. Depending on the context, the approach is different. Here are some examples:

### In single post page

If it's on your single page, you can use :

```
<?php
global $post;
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', $post->post_excerpt );
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', my_focus_keyword' );
?>
```

### In function.php

Place this code in functions.php, it do that after each post saving, in admin section.

```
<?php
// Launch the update_post_meta on post saving.
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_yoast_saved_datas' );

function my_yoast_saved_datas( $post_id, $post ) {

  // Check that your post is what you want
  if ( $_POST['post_type'] == 'post' ) {

    // Check if user can't do that
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }

  update_post_meta( $post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc',  $post->post_excerpt );
  update_post_meta( $post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw',  'my_focus_keyword');
}
?>
```

### Loop to update custom fields in one time

Launch one time, in functions.php or pack it on a plugin to launch on activation.

```
<?php
global $post;

// Array of args, change to your need
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status'=> 'publish' );

// Get alls posts
$my_posts = get_posts( $args );

// Loop on post
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
  setup_postdata( $post );
  global $post;

  // Update on create custom fields
  update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc',  $post->post_excerpt );
  update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw',  'my_focus_keyword');
}

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I try Prefix meta keys with "_" very good, it working